# Android 2.3 set call volume

Tags: audio, calls, volume-control, zte-blade

i tried quite all the options but i can't find the solution.
I already have the volume at maximum when i press the + button during a call.
The phone hadn't this behaviour when i first used it (it is a ZTE-blade).
Maybe(i'm not sure) this started after flashing it with cyanogenmod 7.1 (before it had ginger stir fry)

Is there an option to turn it up? i have a really hard time trying to hear what people says on calls..

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, sometimes the volume is at max and won't decrease, sometimes the other way around. It also started occurring on CM7.1 (but on a Galaxy S). The volume controls start responding after pressing them both ways (i.e. if volume is at maximum, increase first and then decrease, and vice versa).

You should also check if your phone's version has amplification settings in `Settings -> CyanogenMod settings -> Sound` or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately i already tried the "before down then up" and vice versa method, and didn't work (i read about it in some android blog). In addition in cyanogenMod settings, under audio, i just have options for attenuation(or increase) of volume with the headphones..